# Update a query in mongoDB with c#

Tags: c#, mongodb, asp.net-core

Compiler Error CS1061 in x variable, i want to update a query in mongodb but the problem was throwing an error for x.

```
public async Task<string> Update(string id, TEntity user)
    {
        await collection.ReplaceOneAsync(x => x.id == id, user);
        return "";
    }
```

Comment: What is the full message of exception?

Comment: Erreur CS1061 'TEntity' ne contient pas de définition pour 'id' et aucune méthode d'extension accessible 'id' acceptant un premier argument de type 'TEntity' n'a été trouvée (une directive using ou une référence d'assembly est-elle manquante ?) DB

Comment: Then what type is `collection`? And does an element of collection have `id` property inside? Error states that it doesn't

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this code: `ReplaceOneAsync(x => x.id == id, user)` the `x` is of type `TEntity`.

The error says that from the compiler point of view, `TEntity` does not contain property `id`.

One way to solve it is define an abstraction that every `TEntity` must inherit from:

```cs
public interface IEntity
{
   string id { get; set; }
}
```

Then in the repository class (according the method you posted, I assume it is a generic repository class of TEntity), add generic constraint on `TEntity` as follows:

```cs
public class MyRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : IEntity
{
    // collection should be IMongoCollection<TEntity> 
    private IMongoCollection<TEntity> collection; // initialized elsewhere

    public async Task<string> Update(string id, TEntity user)
    {
        await collection.ReplaceOneAsync(x => x.id == id, user);
        return "";
    }

    // ...other members...
}
```

Since we included generic constraint `where TEntity : IEntity`, the compiler now knows that every `TEntity` has a `string id` property.